# Ejecting dll by calling CreateRemoteThread : crash

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to make for myself a tool for extracting/releasing dlls from processes. I have already experienced with LoadLibrary and injecting but this time the logic doesn't seem to apply.
This is my code:

```
HMODULE findModuleOffset(HANDLE proc, char *mod_name) {
    //Finds module address in specified process. 0 if not found
    HMODULE hMods[2048];
    DWORD modules_byte_size;
    if (EnumProcessModules(proc, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &modules_byte_size))
    {
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < (modules_byte_size / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
            CHAR module_name[MAX_PATH];

            // Get the full path to the module's file.

            if (GetModuleFileNameExA(proc, hMods[i], module_name, sizeof(module_name))) {
                if (strcmp(strrchr(module_name,'.')+1,"exe")!=0 && compareExeName(module_name, mod_name)) {
                    return hMods[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
bool compareExeName(char *path, char *partial_name) {
    //This will substract the filename from path and compare it with partial_name
    char *lastSlash = strrchr(path, '\\') + 1;
    if (lastSlash != NULL && strstr(lastSlash, partial_name) == lastSlash) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void unload_all_dll(char *dll_name) {
    DWORD process_ids[2048];
    DWORD process_byte_size;            //size of filled process_ids in BYTES (after the call)
    DWORD process_count;        //count of all elements in process_ids
    HMODULE  ext_dll_module;
    HANDLE opened_process;
    HANDLE Hthread;
    DWORD thread_exit_code = 1;
    CHAR exe_path[1024];

    if (EnumProcesses(process_ids, sizeof(process_ids), &process_byte_size)) {
        process_count = process_byte_size / sizeof(DWORD);

        for (int i = 0; i < process_count; i++) {
            thread_exit_code = 0;
            if ((opened_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, process_ids[i])) == NULL) continue;

            GetModuleFileNameExA(opened_process, 0, exe_path, MAX_PATH);

            if ((ext_dll_module = findModuleOffset(opened_process, dll_name)) != 0) {

                while (thread_exit_code == 0) {
                    if ((Hthread = CreateRemoteThread(opened_process, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "FreeLibrary"), (void*)ext_dll_module, 0, NULL)) == NULL) {
                        cout<<"Process closed meanwhile or dll unloaded";
                        break;  //process has closed meanwhile
                    }
                    while (WaitForSingleObject(Hthread, 1000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT);
                    GetExitCodeThread(Hthread, &thread_exit_code);
                }
                cout << "Dll unloaded from " << exe_path << endl;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Warning:some variables names might be confusing(I am in hurry)
But every time I try to eject a dll everything crashes(of course,only the apps that contained the specfied dll). I tested everything I could and everything seems fine: the module address returned by `findModuleOffset` is good(checked against the value given by process explorer). I have no ideea what the return value of createremotethread or `thread_exit_code` is because the app crashes(it contasins the dll to be ejected..so...). Can you help me?

Comment: Uhm, unless you injected the dll yourself, calling `FreeLibrary` over a dll that is actually in use by the target process code is going to end in a crash... Still, you can always attach a debugger to the target process before trying to unload the dll from it, and see where it crashes.

Comment: Yes ,indeed ,I should have mentioned. The dll is mine and is mostly empty. It has a couple of loops in it. Is this the cause? Shouldn't freelibrary forcefully unload the dll?

Comment: I can't check now with the debugger. I will come back with a response tomorrow.

Comment: If there is some thread in the target process that is running code in that dll (those loops?), of course it is going to crash - it couldn't be any different, the running threads have no way to know that the code they are running is being unmapped from memory.

Comment: Ok more details: I inject that dll using CreateRemoteThread so there is one. In the dll I create two other threads ,one of which is checking the value of a registry(in a loop). That's mostly it. So those threads cause the problem or the first one(used for injecting)?

Comment: Whatever thread that is running code inside the dll is going to crash, so I'd say those last two. Also, I expect the injection thread to be terminated way before you unload the dll, right?

Comment: The answer at your question is yes. I am not sure but is this what freelibraryandexitthread is for?

Comment: No, `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` is for a dll to suicide - i.e., to allow code from the dll itself to unload the dll. Of course no other thread should be running code from the dll.

Comment: Anyhow, you have to coordinate with your running threads to shut themselves down before unloading the dll, using some IPC method. Notice that this avoids the need for further injection, once you can communicate with your threads running in your target processes they can just suicide themselves and unload the dll - this time, yes, with `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`.

Comment: So the solution is to put the code inside the dll for autoejecting(somehow checking on the threads to finish) or...how can I do this externally? I know that it isn't required to call frelibrary but I know that althought the dll finished executing it will still be loaded in mem. I am right?  I am not familiar with IPC (I will look into that). For a quick fix:would it work if I remotely call TerminateThread?

Comment: Put in the loop of one of your threads a check for some signal from the controlling process (you may use a [mailslot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365130(v=vs.85).aspx), for example); when the signal arrives, signal even to the other thread that it must terminate (you may use a shared atomic variable; or, you may re-architect your code to avoid the extra thread, if both are doing polling they can be combined), and finally call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` to suicide both the thread and the dll.

Comment: Thanks I will try avoid the threads or use inter communication to free the dll.Your advice is a fix for my problem so I suggest you to post a complete answer for those might have the same problem.

Comment: I will not be avaible till tomorrow.

Comment: Posted an answer with a summary/some more details about the proposed solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(moving from the comments)

Given that there are threads in the target process that are running code from the dll being unloaded, they are going to crash immediately after the dll gets freed - after all, the very pages of code that the CPU is executing are being unmapped!

To avoid the problem, the running threads have to be notified in some way, so they can terminate before unloading the dll; Windows provides many IPC methods, one rarely used is particularly well-fitted for this case, namely [mailslots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576(v=vs.85).aspx).

When the dll is injected, the "master" thread that gets created will create a mailslot with a well-known name, and periodically check if there's any message for him. When you want to unload the dlls, instead of brutally injecting a thread that forcefully frees the dll, just ask to your "inside man": post a message to the mailslot asking it to terminate<sup>1</sup>.

The thread will see that there's a message in the mailslot, take care to possibly terminate the other threads that were started inside the target process (a shared atomic variable + `WaitForSingleObject` can be used) and, when the cleanup is finished, call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` to suicide both the last thread and the dll.

---

**Notes**

1. A particularly interesting peculiarity of mailslots is that, if they are created multiple times with the same name, messages sent to such a name will be delivered to *all* them, so if, as it seems, you want to shut down all the injected dlls at the same time, this greatly simplifies the controlling program - there's not even need to enumerate the running processes.